# What causes NHibernate “Internal Connection Fatal” errors?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, log4net

When NHibernate’s log level is set to “DEBUG”, we start seeing a bunch of “Internal Connection Fatal” errors in our logs.  It look like NHibernate dies about ½ way through processing a particular result set.  According to the logs, the last column NHibernate reads appears to have garbage in it that isn’t in the underlying data.

**The issue seems to go away when either:**

1. The log level is set back to “ERROR”.
2. The view being queried is changed to return less data (either less rows OR null or blank values for various columns).

We’re using ASP.NET MVC, IIS7, .NET Framework 4.5, SQL Server 2012, log4net.2.0.2 and NHibernate.3.3.3.4001.

I guess my real concern is that there is some hidden issue with the code that the added strain of logging is bringing to light, but I'm not sure what it could be.  I have double checked the NHibernate mappings and they look good.  I've also checked to ensure that I'm disposing of the NHibernate session at the end of each request. I also tried bumping up the command timeout, which didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the columns is of non-simple type (binary, text, etc.) nh may be having problems populating a property.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm only using the following types: varchar, datetime, nvarchar and float.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the connection from our dev app server to our dev database server was wonky.

1. From the dev app server, open SSMS and try to connect to the dev database server.
2. Sometimes we get the "internal connection fatal error", sometimes we don't.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is possibly caused by TCP Chimney Offload/SQL Server incompatibility.

Check the following KB Article for possible solutions:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942861

For Windows 7/2008 R2:

> By default, the TCP Chimney Offload feature is set to Auto. This means
>   that the chimney does not offload all connections. Instead, it
>   selectively offloads the connections that meet the following criteria:
>
> The connection is established through a 10 gigabits per second (Gbps)
>   Ethernet adapter.
>
> The mean round-trip link latency is less than 20
>   milliseconds.
>
> At least 130 kilobytes (KB) of data were exchanged over
>   the connection.

Last condition is triggered in the middle of dataset, so you see garbage instead of real data.